# Column font and width not changing, rest of the table is

Tags: document-library, column

I have a document library with scripts to change the font size of the header row.  All the columns apart from one; "Short Description"; have changed.

I have just added a script to adjust the column width of this column and it's not responding to that either.

I have tested the script on other columns in the table and it works fine.

Its a Multiple Line Text column.  The colour changes for the header row and font have both worked.

Any ideas?

Scripts being used are:

```
    <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("div.ms-vh-div:contains('Topic')").css("width", "500px");});
</script>
```

and

```
    <style>
.ms-viewheadertr a,
.ms-viewheadertr div {
color: white;
}
.ms-vh2 {
font-size: 10pt ! important; }
.ms-vh {
font-size: 10pt ! important; }
.ms-viewheadertr {
font-size: 10pt ! important; }
.ms-viewheadertr {
background-color: #00646e; }
</style>
```

Comment: can you console log $("div.ms-vh-div:contains('Topic')").length?

Comment: I've never used that function before - would I add "//length" to the end of the script and then have a new script console.log(length)?

Comment: just open developer tools of your web browser (press F12 function key), and under console tab write the above code i.e. `$("div.ms-vh-div:contains('Topic')").length` and see what is the output. If it is 0 you dont have that element on page.

Comment: oh that's easier than I thought it would be!  It comes back with syntax error.  I tried it with another columns details to make sure I was doing it correctly, it came back with 1.

Comment: Arey you sure it return a syntax error? Coz the above never never gives syntax error, it'll give the length as a number greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Hmm not sure, it definitely came back with syntax error - no 0s or 1s!

Answer (score 2):

**Problem Solved**. I have faced these situation multiple times and solved by using simple styling. Here I have picked up the header element by its position. Here the column MLOT (multiple Line of Text) is at 7th position. You can choose based on your field's sequence. I have used Script editor web part for this. pls Refer below script:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-listviewtable thead tr th:nth-child(7){
    color: red !important;
    width: 250px !important;
    font-size: xx-large !important;
}
</style>
```

Screen Shot:

[image]

Comment: Is there a limit on the column width?

Comment: No limits on column width.

Answer (score 0):

Put a script editor web part on the page and add following code. This will change the header styling.

```
<style>
.ms-listviewtable th{font-size: 24px;}
</style>
```

If you want to change the header of only one column then use script suggested by @DvG